# Tutorial Question: Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, ros-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm new to ROS and following the standard tutorial given on the ROS.ORG site. While running based on the topic of writing a simple publisher and subscriber, the outputs for talker and listener are shown below:

**Talker output:**
[INFO] hello world 1
[INFO] hello world 2
[INFO] hello world 3
[INFO] hello world 4
[INFO] hello world 5
[INFO] hello world 6
[INFO] hello world 7
[INFO] hello world 8

**Listener output**

[INFO] hello world 3
[INFO] hello world 4
[INFO] hello world 5
[INFO] hello world 6
[INFO] hello world 7
[INFO] hello world 8

---

It seems that "hello world 0", "hello world 1" and "hello world 2" are missing from the listener.

I have used the original source code given on the topic.

Is this normal, how come they are missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40896/tutorial-question:-writing-a-simple-publisher-and-subscriber-(c++)/) by [bg_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2997/bg_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is normal.

Your code starts publishing right away, but in the background the two nodes first have to find each other and handle out a connection. Until that is done the messages are published to nowhere.

You can check when there is a connection by using `pub.getNumSubscribers()`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3